# ror - include foreign key at both ends of has_many and belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I'm inheriting code which has:

```
class Graphic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => 'asset_id',  
  :conditions => 'asset_type_id = 5', 
  :order => 'created_at', :dependent => :destroy

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :graphic, :foreign_key => :asset_id
```

It seems to me like the has_many should not have the foreign_key (it's referenced in the belongs_to ok I believe) but I am not sure, do you know?

i.e. should it be

```
class Graphic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments,  
  :conditions => 'asset_type_id = 5', 
  :order => 'created_at', :dependent => :destroy

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :graphic, :foreign_key => :asset_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something that is already baked in Rails. You should use Polymorphic Associations here.

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :asset, :polymorphic => true
end

class Graphic
  has_many :comments, :as => :assets
end
```

This way, you need to declare foreign_key on neither side.

Comment: That's true too... I was just trying to answer his question haha.

Answer (score 3):

In a `has_many` statement for rails, `:foreign_key` is indeed an option which has this description in the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and “_id” suffixed. So a Person class that makes a has_many association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key.

So in your case, it looks as though you do need the `foreign_key` attribute on your `has_many` statement, since it differs from the name of the class.

However, you shouldn't need the `foreign_key` declaration in your `belongs_to` statement.  Here is the description for the `:foreign_key` option for a `belongs_to` relationship in [the ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to):

> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly, belongs_to :favorite_person, :class_name => "Person" will use a foreign key of “favorite_person_id”.

I'm assuming that what you really meant to write for your `Comment` class is this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :graphic, :foreign_key => :graphic_id
```

In this case you could simplify the `belongs_to` statement to simply this:

```
belongs_to :graphic
```

Comment: I think he really means asset_id, which may or may not be graphic

Comment: The two quotes are too similar. I don't get why the `:foreign_key` is overridden in the Model with `has_many`, when it is the Model with `belongs_to` which will actually have the foreign-key in it's table.